# Creating javascript variable for dynamic element

Tags: javascript

I have a div which contains message updates sent by users. How can I assign a javascript variable to this div so that it's value is always the current content of the div which is consistently updating with messages?

```
var x = document.getElementById("MessageBox"); // only equals value at the 
// time rather than present value
```

Comment: where and how are you getting the new data?

Comment: poll it to get the values for a certain interval. You cant get the values like referencing the div element in one variable.

Comment: Either you can add a script block after the html region that gets updated and assign the new value to the variable or you can add a polling to your page which continuously monitor the value change.

Comment: x.innerHTML should give you the current value. right?

Comment: The new data is received from user's input. It's a very basic websocket chat and I'm trying to create a variable which has the text value of the content of the div.

Comment: What are you doing with this variable? Why can't you just reference x.innerHTML when needed?

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon it's a very bad idea to store HTML data. Store instead an Array of objects`[{},{}]` with the received data: `[{userID:123,time:123456789,message:"hello world"}, {......]` that way you don't need to do the same work all over again, simply receive from your socket your JSON Array Object and you have it, loop the keys to retrieve the needed data. you can easily add new data to it using `Array.prototype.push( userChatMsgObject )` and so on...

Comment: I'm passing this variable on a querystring and presenting it on another page. When I pass the variable on with x.innerHTML it displays blank, similarly if I do something like x.innerText or x.textContent it is 'undefined'. I took to checking my console and I saw that 'x' was not updating it's value.

Comment: When I say "presenting it on another page" I mean that the variable will be displayed as the text message.

Comment: try using some MVVM frameworks like knockout.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to assign an [`.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange) event handler to the element, then assign the node's value to a variable held outside the scope of the function:

```
var myMSGvalue;
document.getElementById("MessageBox").onchange = function () {
    myMSGvalue = this.value;
    // this will work for <input>, not <div>
}
```

If you really need to assign your data to an html element, you should use an `<input type="hidden">`.

However, it would be much better to assign the data to a variable before you append it to the page. For example, let's say you have a web socket:

```
var messages = [];
socket.on("msg", function (msg) {
    messages.push(msg);
    // msg: { content: "Hello!", author: "notSure" };
    functionToAppendToPage(msg);
})
```

Now, you can see all the messages received in `messages` and `messages[messages.length - 1]` will return the last message received (provided at least one message has been received).

Comment: Typo in the handler. `msMSGvalue`

Comment: does div support onchange event? I think it supports only <input type="checkbox">, <input type="file">, <input type="password">, <input type="radio">, <input type="range">, <input type="search">, <input type="text">, <keygen>, <select> and <textarea> - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Hey roy, now when I type myMSGvalue in the console it gives me back 'undefined'

Answer (score 3):

If your message box field getting data using any Api or through Ajax. You can update the variable before assigning value to message box.